# AngularJS: Component Tree & How to Handle IDs of Newly Created Entities (via HTTP)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, angularjs-directive

I'm using Angular 1. I have a todo list application with a smart (container) component doing server-side interaction, and a dumb/pure/stateless presentation component that displays a list of todos and a text field to create a new one. The presentation component has has an `onCreate` event binding, so the parent component can POST a `Todo` to the server whenever it's created.

```
<todo-container>
<todo-list todos="vm.todos" on-create="vm.postTodoToServer($event)"> </todo-list>
</todo-container>
```

Each `Todo` in the `<todo-list>` presentation component should also have an ID so PUT/PATCH/DELETE operations can be performed (we will implement `onUpdate` and `onDelete` bindings for `<todo-list>` in the future. However, for newly added `Todo`s, I won't know that ID until the `Todo` is POSTed to the server. Thus, `<todo-container>` has to give `<todo-list>` the ID of a newly created `Todo` when the server finally responds.

How do I handle this use case in an elegant way without tightly coupling the two components? I may want to use `<todo-list>` inside a different container elsewhere in the app (maybe without server-side interaction).

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a UUID generator from a utilities library as a temporary id when the data only exists on the client side. You can also make the id negative, so that your server process knows that, when the to-do item is posted, it doesn't actually exist on the server yet, so a real id needs to be assigned to it in keeping with the server id pattern. Then just overwrite the to-do list item with the real, server assigned data returned by the POST call.

Lodash (a utility library), for example, has a unique id generator function.